# Android: Multiple Column ListView from Single Data

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I tried to make a ListView with multiple column from a single array of strings.

I have tried to search some references, but every questions asked out there is quite different with what I'm trying to do. Generally, they are trying to show different data in different column in a ListView.

While, what I want is Multiple Column from single data array.
For example:

```
ListView

Column-1     Column-2

Data1        Data2

Data3        Data4

Data5        Data6

DataN        DataN+1
```

Something like this, and also with single scrollbar.

So, I wanted to see the data array splitted to two column at once.

Comment: Please add some code that you have tried.

Comment: @Nidheesh Sorry but,I don't see the need to post a code at a question like this. Firstly, I'm looking for a suggestion not fixing my current code. Second, how can I post a code when I don't know how to do it at the first place ? It will be no differences with a code using a SimpleAdapter. I think you misunderstood my context here. CMIIW. Thanks.

Comment: Try using Arraylist<Hashmap<String, String>> and SimpleAdapter as listview Adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a sample using Arraylist Hashmap.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> DataList = new ArrayList<>();
```

This how you add items in Arraylist Hashmap

```
HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

data.put("column1", "column1 value");
data.put("column2", "column2 value");
data.put("column3", "column3 value");

DataList.add(data); //1 row of item added in DataList
```

This how you use the SimpleAdapter

```
SimpleAdapter Adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, DataList,
                R.layout.YOUR_LISTVIEW_LAYOUT, new String[]{"column1", "column", "column3"},
                new int[]{R.id.column1_textview, R.id.column2_textview, R.id.column3_textview});
        YOUR_LISTVIEW.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

**YOUR_LISTVIEW.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/column1_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/column2_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/column3_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi @L2_Paver.

Thank you very much for your unique idea.
It did actually solved the case of my problem example in my question.
So, I will marked it as the solution.

But, in case other reader are looking for more flexibility and customization for the same problem. For example L2_Paver answer is good, but might has limitation with independent OnItemClickListener for each data and It's View customization. I suggest to see RecyclerView + GridLayoutManager for more control. Thx